# Custom popup with custom button in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have written my code to do following functionality: When I click my image, custom popup view with close(customized) button will show up. But the problem is, when I click on the close button, the popup is removed but the close button is still there.

My code is:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) UIView *viewPopup;

-(void)imageclick
{

_viewPopup=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 100, 350, 360)];
 [_viewPopup setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
 _viewPopup.alpha=0.4f;
 [self.view addSubview:_viewPopup];

 [self addCloseBtn]; //custom close button

  }
```

How can I modify my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
[closebuttonObject removeFromSuperview];
```